# Regular Expression Mismatch

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to match values that come in this format:

```
, ####-####-####-####
, ####-########-#####
, ##-###-#-###-##-#-####
```

For example: `2018-03-10, 2018-02-10-2019, 10-20-2016`

should only capture `, 2018-02-10-2019` but it's capturing all of the line.

The `,` at the start is optional. I'm basically trying to find values that have 3 or more hyphens in them.

Here is what I am using:

```
(, )?([\/-]?)(\d+[\/-]?){4,}
```

This is not only capturing the values I want, but it's also capturing values like this:

```
30/05/2018
```

Can someone help me troubleshoot this?

Edit #1:

This is not a duplicate question, one is matching via hyphens and another is matching digits. They are in different locations and represent different things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Mismatch: Searching anywhere for certain number of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050018/regex-mismatch-searching-anywhere-for-certain-number-of-digits)

Comment: Not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex `(\d+(?:\-\d+){3,})`.

`\d+` makes it so that the match should contain digits in the beginning.

`(?:\-\d+){3,}` matches a hyphen and any number of digits following it repeated 3 or more times. The ?: is for to make the group (The part inside parenthesis) as a non capture group so that this group results wont be returned in the match (Eg. re.findall).

Comment: so a non-capture group basically makes sure that it exists, but won't return it? Absolutely nothing gets returned if the value the non-capturing group does not exist, correct?