# Regex Mismatch: Searching anywhere for certain number of digits

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to match values that come in this format:

```
, ####-####-####-#######
, ####-########-#####
, ######-###-#-###-##-#-####
, ##-####-#####-#-######
```

For example: `2018-03-10, 2018123-02-10-2019, 10-20-20232316`

should only capture `,  2018123-02-10-2019, 10-20-20232316`.

The `,` at the start is optional. I'm basically trying to find values that have 5 or more digits in them, located together, between a comma. i.e. `12345`  not    `123 other stuff 45`.

My solution is to write 3 lines of regex looking at the start, end, and middle. The start and end are fine, but I am not sure how to go about the middle.

Can someone help me troubleshoot this?

**Edit #1:**

Context provided:

I am taking a regular expression and using a replace function replace a hodgepodge of different values that all came back when I tried to extract dates.

I am literally doing things like `".replace(('regular expression':'aaaaaa (this gets filtered out'), regex=True)`

**Edit #2:**

I am using [regexone](https://regex101.com/) to test my results.

I tried using `(?=,?)[^, ]*\d{5,}[^,]*` but for some reason it's matching 1 value it shouldn't be matching.

[image: sample from regex editor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = '2018-03-10, 354687-56987-314, 2018123-02-10-2019, 10-20-20232316'
re.findall(r'[^, ]*\d{5,}[^,]*',data)

Out[847]: ['354687-56987-314', '2018123-02-10-2019', '10-20-20232316']
```

## EDIT

from the examples given the regex `\S*\d{5,}[^,\s]*` can be used

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
text = "2018-03-10, 2018123-02-10-2019, 10-20-20232316"
re.findall(r'\w+(?:-\w+)+',text)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant 5 or more digits together, not located anywhere. I.e. 12345 not 123 stuff 45

Comment: This captures "2018-03-10" as well as the other stuff, I do not want "2018-03-10" because it does not have 5 digits before the comma. 5 digits have to be located, together, side by side, somewhere between commas

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex. This will capture anything with 5 or more consecutive digits.

```
r'.*(\d{5,}).*'
```